# Run function on multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a VB Excel function that runs on the contents of a worksheet. I am using the ActiveSheet object to access the sheet’s contents. The function runs fine on one a one-sheet workbook. But if the function is applied to two sheets in a single book, the ActiveSheet’s contents is used to calculate values on both sheets.

How do I target the worksheet that the function's cell is contained within? Thanks.

Comment: Fully qualify your `Cells`, `Range`, `Rows`, etc references.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1503/ranges-and-cells/20029/ways-to-refer-to-a-single-cell#t=201705110434425598762 for some guidelines, or refer to the other question that I have just suggested that this is a "duplicate" of.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run the same code on all the worksheets in an Excel file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952194/how-to-run-the-same-code-on-all-the-worksheets-in-an-excel-file)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the Worksheet attached to the Range passed into the function:

```
currentWS = aRange.Worksheet
```